# Plug-in won't update on Google App engine Dev server for Wordpress? (hangs)

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I now have Wordpress running on a local GAE Dev server. The local copy reached out to the mother ship and seems to want to update a few things.

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04
WordPress 3.8.1 running Twenty Fourteen theme.
It seems that WP want to update to 3.91
You have version 1.0 installed. Update to 1.2. View version 1.2 details.
You have version 1.3 installed. Update to 1.4. View version 1.4 details.
and some theme updates..

I tried to just update the plug-ins and it just seems to hang, I tried both plugins (batcache manager and GAE) and then only selecting the GAE plug in, both attempts gave me the message that the update was beginning, wait.. but even after extended time,, no progress....

I had downloaded the zip version of the GAE WP from Github Do I need to clone the repo instead??

Or.. should I try to run the upgrade to 3.9.1 on the dev server?

Should the auto update function on the local dev server? I assume so since it does not seem that it can be done on the production GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These plugins only work in GAE. There is no need to activate them on the development server.

See: [How to update Wordpress plugins in local copy of Wordpress for App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504845/how-to-update-wordpress-plugins-in-local-copy-of-wordpress-for-app-engine)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but my question is about updating them, not running them? As well as updating the base version of WP.. Reading the GitHub repo it seems that it is up to date but the zip file was not,, So simplistically it would seem best to clone the repo,, the broader question still is.. does the WP auto update mechanism work on the dev server for future maintenance?

Comment: The question that I linked to is about updating, not running.

Comment: Ahh,, well I'm going ahead with a GIT clone.. Xing fingers

Comment: The GIT clone has all updated, WP and Plugins and Themes.. The ZIP file is out of date